Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: LinkedMap in instance of org.apache.flink.cdc.debezium.DebeziumSourceFunction
Trying to connect to mongoDB using FlinkSQL. Created maven project and implemented the java code. after building the jar and submitted to flink cluster.
Flink version - 1.19.0
Please find the code below
public class mongoDB
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
            StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

            String sqlToRun = "CREATE TABLE flinkSql1 ("
                    +"_id String,"
                    + "Name String,"
                    + "Age String,"
                    + "PRIMARY KEY(_id) NOT ENFORCED"
                    + ") WITH ("
                    + "'connector' = 'mongodb-cdc',"
                    + "'hosts' = 'njbnet.com:27009',"
                    + "'username' = 'user',"
                    + "'password' = 'bX2Y%3FVSz',"
                    + "'database' = 'eric',"
                    + "'collection' = 'flinkSql',"
                    + "'connection.options' = 'authSource=admin'"
                    +")";

            tableEnv.executeSql(sqlToRun);
            String insertQuery = "SELECT * FROM flinkSql1";
            TableResult result = tableEnv.executeSql(insertQuery);
            result.print();
            env.execute("Job Submission");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}

Executing the above code in the flink cluster and getting the below exception
Caused by: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot instantiate user function.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:417)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain.<init>(OperatorChain.java:169)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.<init>(RegularOperatorChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:730)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:712)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:751)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap to field org.apache.flink.cdc.debezium.DebeziumSourceFunction.pendingOffsetsToCommit of type org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap in instance of org.apache.flink.cdc.debezium.DebeziumSourceFunction
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2076)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.checkObjectFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:2039)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkObjFieldValueTypes(ObjectStreamClass.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultCheckFieldValues(ObjectInputStream.java:2512)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2419)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2496)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2390)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2228)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1687)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:489)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:447)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:539)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.deserializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:527)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.readObjectFromConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:481)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.getStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:401)
    ... 9 more

Please find the dependecies which I am using
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-mongodb-cdc</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons.collections</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-java-bridge</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0-1.19</version>
        </dependency>

Tried with diffrent version of the dependencies still getting the same error
